# RegEx for ${any_text}

Tags: regex, apache, freemarker

I'm trying to find any solution to extract all variables definition from freemaker template. Lets assume that template looks like this:

```
Hello ${test_1} Hello ${test_2} Hello ${test_3} Hello ${test_4}
```

At the output I want to have list of test_1, test_2, test_3, test_4. I tried almost every approach but this $ (special character sign) is causing me a lot of problems also important thing (that also cause me problem) are variables that relate for objects for example ${test_1.user.name}

Comment: `\$\{([\w.]+)\}` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jfprJY/1/) should work...

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [dawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298607/dawg) user the solution for this looks like:

```
\$\{([\w.]+)\}
```

One more time than you very much.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jfprJY/1/)